# Prove $A\cap(A'\cap B')'=A$ using set equivalence laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble using set equivalence laws to prove the following.

$$A\cap(A'\cap B')'=A$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use \cap  \cup to write intersection and union in latex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give the algebraic derivation of the statement in supplement to Davids nice pictorials.

---

By the [De Morgan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for the complement, we first derive

$$A\cap (A'\cap B')'=A\cap ((A')'\cup (B')')$$

By elementary properties of the complement, that is $(X')'=X$, we have

$$A\cap ((A')'\cup (B')')=A\cap (A\cup B)$$

Now, $\cap$ distributes over $\cup$, i.e.

$$A\cap (A\cup B)=(A\cap A)\cup (A\cap B)=A\cup (A\cap B)$$

as $A\cap A=A$. Now, as $A\cap B\subseteq A$, we have $A\cup (A\cap B)=A$.

Comment: I would also like to know the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I think the possible reason for downvote is that you gave a whole answer for a PSQ where the OP has showed no effort.

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote your answer. It was very clear and I very much appreciate the time and effort that you took to answer it for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes figures are worth 1000 words:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$A \cap (A'\cap B')'$$

as by morgan's law  $(P \cap Q)'= P'\cup Q' $

thus $$(A'\cap B')'=A \cup B$$

$$A \cap (A \cup B) $$ 
$$(A \cap A) \cup (A \cap B)$$
$$A \cap A =A $$
$$A \cup (A \cap B)$$
By Venn diagram, it is clear that it is nothing but A

Comment: why the downvote though I don't understand??

Comment: I think the possible reason for downvote is that you gave a whole answer for a PSQ where the OP has showed no effort.

Comment: but this is just crazy on this site if I write a hint I get downvoted or if I write a full answer I get downvoted don't know what to do just pray

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote your answer. It was very clear and I very much appreciate the time and effort that you took to answer it for me.